# How to use Iphone as a router for a local network, (Not RPI as a router)?

Tags: ssh

I set my RPi to have a fixed IP.

First Scenario:
After connecting my RPi to my WiFi
I opened Terminal on my mac, type ssh pi@192.168.0.38 and I log in with password raspberry. **It workes.**

Second Scenario:
I create a Personal Hotspot using my iPhone.
I connect my RPi to that Personal Hotspot.
I connect my Mac to that Personal Hotspot.
I opened Terminal on my mac, type ssh pi@192.168.0.38 and

After a while, the terminal shows

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.38 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: This is not a Pi question but an iPhone issue.

Comment: I really need help, and maybe other people will have the same issue. Apple doesn't care about Raspberry Pi trying to use their iPhone hotspot.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the IP address of the Raspberry Pi is not 192.168.0.38. What does running 'hostname -I' show on the Raspberry Pi?

Edit to add: The local subnet created by the personal hotspot likely is not 192.168.0.0/24. Let the Raspberry Pi get its address via DHCP from the hotspot instead of a fixed address.

Comment: The static ip address is `192.168.0.38` without any doubt. It works on the WiFi (whatever WiFi is meant).

Comment: | . pi@raspberrypi:~ $ hostname -I" .  |
| . "192.168.0.38" . | .    My Raspberry Pi definitely has the IP 192.168.0.38 that I fixed to be. I cannot let the DHCP give a ramdom IP to my Raspberry pi. I have some ESP8266 that talks to my RPi via MQTT, so my Raspberry Pi needs to have a static IP address.

Comment: One possible way is if your router has the capability to act as a wireless bridge. It connects to the iphone hotspot and the RPi and Mac remain connected to the routers WLAN. Another option is if the iPhone hotspot internal network can be changed to the 192.168.0.0/24 but AFAIK, there is no such option in the settings.  A third option is to get a wireless USB adapter for your RPi. This connects to the iPhone hotspot while the on board RPi wifi connects to your home router.